# date change script troubleshoot

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a simple sheets script that changes certain cell dates with the current date. I also have a trigger in place that executes once a day, and the execution log indicates the script executes successfully. But when I open the sheet (of a multiple sheet workbook), the date did not change.

I want the script to change the date without me opening the file and running it. But it does not appear to do this. It only changes the date when I run the script with the sheet open. Below is the script.

---

```
    function updateSpecificCells() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var cellList = ['A4', 'A5', 'A9', 'A10'];
  var currentDate = new Date();
  
  cellList.forEach(function(cellReference) {
    var cell = sheet.getRange(cellReference);
    cell.setValue(currentDate);
  });
}
```

Comment: I believe on open is a simple trigger so if you’re using the on open trigger, you might want to change it to an installable trigger. If you’re using a custom function, then I don’t think custom functions can change the content of other cells. You didn’t really explain how you’re triggering it so I can’t be sure.

Comment: Thank you. That's probably it. Google doesn't seem to show you that it's "on open" versus "edit" unless you delete it and start again where it shows you that option.

Comment: Just to save you some problems I should let you know that you will want to namee the onOpen handler function something other than onOpen otherwise it will fire on two different triggers and can be difficult to debug.